# How to automatically add the necessary dependencies in Android Studio?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, dependencies

I have a Kotlin Android Studio project I am making that integrates with Firebase. I added all the lines required listed in Firebase's instructions into **build.gradle** for both the Project level and the App level.

But this doesn't include any of the dependencies my project seems to need, I get an error when trying to build and these warnings:

[image: Gradle Sync Warnings]

The **Declared Dependencies** list for my app module only has the two Firebase dependencies, and not any of the dependencies as listed by the above warnings:

[image: Declared Dependencies]

I noticed there are some dependencies I assume I need in **All Modules**:

[image]

Is there a way I can add those into my app module folder? I am not sure if that's how it works so let me know.

If this is not the way, please let me know how I can add all these required dependencies quickly onto my Project (preferrably without manually searching each one's repository url and such) so that I can Sync and Build without any errors.

Comment: Have you tried to update Kotlin to the latest version?

Comment: I did just now and the errors are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gradle Sync was just now successful, here's what happened:

- During the editing of the **build.gradle** files, Google Firebase's instructions were to add this line of code to the Project level's **build.gradle** file:

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    
      }
      dependencies {
        ...
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    
      }
    }
    
    allprojects {
      ...
      repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    
        ...
      }
    }
```

- When Syncing the files through Gradle, an error occurred stating that **settings.gradle** was prefered to **build.gradle**, as it also contains repositories and dependencies. The fix was to remove the ***dependencyResolutionManagement*** code block in **settings.gradle**.

Here's what I did to **fix** all the Sync Warnings and Build errors:

1. Added the same dependencies found in settings.gradle to build.gradle in the Project level:

```
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
```

2. It did not work yet, so then I noticed you also need to add it under the allprojects code block. It will then look something like this:

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()    // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  
    
      }
      dependencies {
        ...
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    
      }
    }
    
    allprojects {
      ...
      repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()    // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  
    
        ...
      }
    }
```

And that was all. After that the Gradle Sync took a long time this time and completed successfully without any errors, and the Build worked as well and ran fine as expected.